# ReactJs and D3.js : Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at responseJson

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, d3.js, topojson

In my App.js,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as d3 from "d3";
import * as d3queue from 'd3-queue';
import * as topojson from 'topojson';

var usState = require("./us-states.json");
var usCounty = require("./us-counties.json");

var imageModule=new ImageModule(imageOpts);
var queue = d3queue.queue();

var path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);

class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
  super();
  this.drawDoc = this.drawDoc.bind(this);
  }

  drawState(){
    queue.defer(d3.csv, './data.csv', function (d) {
            return {
                id: +(d.state + d.county),
                state: d.state,
                county: d.county,
                unemployment: +d.unemployment
            }
        })
        .defer(d3.json, usState)
        .defer(d3.json, usCounty)
        .awaitAll(this.initializeIt)
  }

  initializeIt(error, results) {
      if (error) { throw error }
      var data = results[0]
}

}
```

On click of button i am calling the drawState method. But i am getting this error "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at responseJson"
and "Uncaught (in promise) {: ""}" . If i am running the above code without react in it , it is working fine. With react i am facing this issue.

Comment: That error means a file is not loading properly. You have an invalid path to one of your files. My guess would be ./data.csv. If you open your developer tools and goto sources tab, find data.csv and select it, I bet it is empty, because it didn't actually load.

Comment: @KyleRichardson , yeah it didn't load . I am not sure why it is not getting loaded , its in the same directory.

Comment: Are you using react-router? If so, make sure you have a `base` tag in your document head... That one's gotten me before.

Comment: You got any solution yet? Because i am facing the same problem now.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I got the same problem with you and now I fix it.

You should put your json files in the public directory:

[image]

Comment: This fixed my issue too, hours after checking. Once moved to the public it needs to be passed to d3 like this `d3.fetch('/data.json')`.